# ggplot and shiny , why is the below syntax not working

Tags: ggplot2, shiny

The below lines works in normal ggplot r studio but when tried with Shiny this doesn't work.

```
p <- ggplot(v_data, aes(x=v_data$date, y=v_data$Val1, colour=v_data$category)) + 
                                                                              geom_line()
```

But the below syntax works in Shiny + ggplot

```
p <- ggplot(v_data, aes(x=date, y=Val1, colour=category)) + geom_line()
   print(p)
```

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example of what you have that works and what doesn't. Here you don't provide data, a Shiny environment, or any information about your R environment, like what packages are being called, etc.  You should also use the formatting tags so that we can understand what is and isn't code a bit easier.

Comment: I think this is the answer
   
 
It's related to the way ggplot scopes itself inside a function

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your `server.R`:

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(v_data, aes(x=date, y=Val1, colour=category)) + geom_line()
})
```

and this in your `ui.R`:

```
plotOutput("plot")
```